# Erros JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estou a ter erros no JavaScript no meu codigo, no inicio haviam mais erros, mas percebi que so trocar a ordem do bootstrap e do javascript, feito isso os erros diminuiram mas ainda sobraram estes, alguem pode ajudar-me?

[image: Imagens dos erros no browser]

Comment: A imagem da pra ver os erros, porém para obter ajuda poste seu código depois o erro.

Answer (score 0):

Ao utilizar Boostrap.js e jQuery a ordem de carregamento dos scripts deverá ser a seguinte:

1. jquery
2. bootstrap.js
3. outras libraries.js se existirem
4. o seu código js